# Liquibase with Java 13: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException

Tags: java, hibernate, liquibase, liquibase-hibernate

Basically, I use Liquibase for most of my Java projects (at least where db migrations are needed) and it worked always on Java 8. I have a requirement now to migrate an existing project to Java 13. The project compiles with the Java 8 and also with Java 13 (see the configuration below), however, Liquibase Maven plug-in (mvn liquibase:diff) throws an ClassLoadingException:

```
org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [com.mypackage.TestEntity]: Could not load requested class : com.mypackage.TestEntity
```

here is the plugin configuration in my POM file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${liquibase.maven.plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <propertyFile>src/main/resources/db-migrations/liquibase/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
        <changeLogFile>src/main/resources/db-migrations/liquibase/db-changelog-master.xml</changeLogFile>
        <diffChangeLogFile>${changeset.output.dir}/${timestamp} - ${desc}.xml</diffChangeLogFile>
        <logging>info</logging>
    </configuration>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase.ext</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-hibernate5</artifactId>
            <version>${liquibase-hibernate5.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${springboot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>${validation-api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>${javassist.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb.api.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

and the liquibase.properties:

```
url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/user_registrations
username=postgres
password=somepwd
driver=org.postgresql.Driver
referenceUrl=hibernate:spring:com.mypackage?dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect&hibernate.physical_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringPhysicalNamingStrategy&hibernate.implicit_naming_strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
```

As I mentioned it at the beginning, the Java 13 build doesn't work:

```
<maven.compiler.release>13</maven.compiler.release>
<java.version>13</java.version>
```

All dependencies have the latest version.

Any idea what could be an issue here? Thanks for any input...

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?
I'm having the same problem

Comment: Same error here, any solution found?